# SQL CASE with one condition and multiple results

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm writing a stored procedure which takes a string as one of the input parameter and then retrieve result.

I'm familiar with the below SQL `CASE` format.

```
CASE
  WHEN col1 in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
  THEN 'HELLO'    
  WHEN col1 in ('val4', 'val5', 'val6') 
  THEN 'WORLD'    
END AS col2
```

What should be the query for other way around?

Like when I give `col2` value as `'HELLO'`, it should return all the rows with `col1` containing `'val1', 'val2', 'val3'`

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in another query...

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT CASE
             WHEN col1 in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
             THEN 'HELLO'    
             WHEN col1 in ('val4', 'val5', 'val6') 
             THEN 'WORLD'    
             END AS col2
...
     )t
WHERE t.col2 = 'HELLO'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WHERE 1 = CASE
  WHEN (col2 = 'HELLO' and col1 in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3'))
    OR (col2 = 'WORLD' and col1 in ('val4', 'val5', 'val6'))
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END
```

or, more simply..

```sql
WHERE  (col2 = 'HELLO' and col1 in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3'))
    OR (col2 = 'WORLD' and col1 in ('val4', 'val5', 'val6'))
```

Answer (score 0):

where (col2 = 'HELLO' and col1 in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3'))
   or (col2 = 'WORLD' and col1 in ('val4', 'val5', 'val6'))

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
SELECT
   col1,
   CASE
   WHEN col1 in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
   THEN 'HELLO'    
   WHEN col1 in ('val4', 'val5', 'val6') 
   THEN 'WORLD'    
   END AS col2
FROM
   --wherever you are getting your data from...
WHERE
   col2 = :SEARCH
```

which will return results tht look like this when you pass HELLO into the bind variable.

```
col1 col2
---- ----
val1 HELLO
val2 HELLO
val3 HELLO
```

If you only want col1 returned, you could do something like this

```
WITH SEARCH_RESULTS AS
(
   SELECT
      col1,
      CASE
      WHEN col1 in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
      THEN 'HELLO'    
      WHEN col1 in ('val4', 'val5', 'val6') 
      THEN 'WORLD'    
      END AS col2
   FROM
      --wherever you are getting your data from...
   WHERE
      col2 = :SEARCH
)

SELECT col1 FROM SEARCH_RESULTS
```